# How to avoid multiple svg elements from being created?

Tags: d3.js, angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to build a D3 chart in angular2 component. When ever I click on the link to create D3 chart it creates a new instance of it. Please notice the HTML where multiple copies of SVG tags are created. any ideas why is it happening and how to avoid it?
[image]
every time i click on the link to create a D3 chart, it should clear/null the existing instance and create a fresh chart component.

Code to create the new instance from the parent component,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BubbleChart } from '../Charts/BubbleChart';

@Component({
    template: `
<div id="divBubbleChart">
    <bubble-chart></bubble-chart>
</div>
`,
    directives: [BubbleChart]
})

export class CacheVisualization {
    constructor() {
        console.log("CacheVisualization component being called");
    }
}
```

the child d3 component

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Configuration } from '../Configuration/Configuration';

declare var d3: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'bubble-chart',
    styleUrls: ['css/BubbleChart.css'],
    providers: [Configuration, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    template: ``,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None 
})
export class BubbleChart {
    public resultData: any;
    public chartData: any;
    margin = 5;
    diameter = 660;

    constructor(private _Configuration: Configuration) {
        console.log("In constructor of BubbleChartComponent");
        this.DrawBubbleChart();
    }

    private DrawBubbleChart(): void {
        console.log("Inside DrawBubbleChart in BubbleChartComponent");
        //console.log(this.resultData);

        var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([-1, 5])
            .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
            .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

        var pack = d3.layout.pack()
            .padding(2)
            .size([this.diameter - this.margin, this.diameter - this.margin])
            .value(function (d) { return d.size; })

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", this.diameter)
            .attr("height", this.diameter)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.diameter / 2 + "," + this.diameter / 2 + ")");

        var chart = d3.json(this._Configuration.BLUESKYDATACACHEAPI_GETEXTRACTORQUEUESLATEST, (error, root) => {
            if (error) throw error;

            var focus = root,
                nodes = pack.nodes(root),
                view;

            var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
                .style("fill", (d) => { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
                .on("click", (d) => { if (focus !== d) zoom.call(this, d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

            var text = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
                .style("display", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

            var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

            d3.select("body")
                .style("background", "white")
                //.style("vertical-align", "top")
                //.style("background", color(-1))
                .on("click", () => { zoom.call(this, root); });

            zoomTo.call(this, [root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + this.margin]);

            function zoom(d) {
                var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

                var transition = d3.transition()
                    .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                    .tween("zoom", (d) => {
                        var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + this.margin]);
                        return (t) => { zoomTo.call(this, i(t)); };
                    });

                transition.selectAll("text")
                    .filter(function (d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
                    .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
                    .each("start", function (d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
                    .each("end", function (d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
            }

            function zoomTo(v) {
                var k = this.diameter / v[2]; view = v;
                node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
                circle.attr("r", function (d) { return d.r * k; });
            }//end zoomTo

        });//end chart

    }//end DrawBubbleChart

}
```

After assigning the ID to the component created, it creates ID for the parent html tag and not for the "svg" tag. refer the snapshot below[image]

Comment: This is not about multiple Angular2 components being created. What is created is outside Angular2 and probably caused by the external D3 JS library (which might be wrapped by an Angular2 component). I guess you need to delete the generated chart before you create a new one, but because this is not caused by Angular2, it probably can't be fixed using Angular2 methods.

Comment: ok, how do i delete the generated chart here? any ideas? or should i need to find the DOM element and clear it before creating a new instance?

Comment: i would recommend when creating the svg, i.e **** var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") **** give it an id of anything you want, for example, 'mySVG'. Like ****.attr('id', 'mySVG')**** and then before it remove '#mySVG'. So d3.select('#mySVG').remove(). Then this will solve the duplicate problem. Make sure you give it an id before you append anything to it obviously

Comment: @thatOneGuy, i tried the way you suggested, but it includes the ID attribute to the parent/selector html tag and not this component i.e. svg here. refer the snapshot attached. following is the code i added..         d3.select("bubble-chart")
                .attr('id', 'mySVG')

Comment: I know you found a solution but in your question youre selection 'body' not 'bubble-chart' so obviously it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove elements that you are creating, you should remove them when you remove your component. Angular 2 has `OnDestory` [lyfecycle hook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html). Try to implement it.
Inside it you you remove svg element from body.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  // save the element on creation and..
  // remove element from body here
}
```

Comment: I have combined the logic suggested by @thatOneGuy in the OnDestory() and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Check if svg element already exists before creating SVG element 
d3.select("body").append("svg"). If exists use that instead of appending a new SVG

```
var svg = d3.select('#mySVG').transition()
```

Solution 2: Create a new function that should be invoked for chart update 'UpdateDrawBubbleChart()'. In BubbleChart constructor check if instance of the class already exists and call 'UpdateDrawBubbleChart', in this function either remove SVG element or use d3 transition.